# How to deep-copy a class object in Python3

Tags: python, class, deep-copy

**GIVEN**:

```
class A:
   x = 4711
B = COPY(A)
setattr(B, "x", "0815")
print("A: %s; B: %s;" % (A.x, B.x))
```

**GOAL**:

An operation `COPY` such that the code fragment above results in

```
A: 4711; B: 0815;
```

**IN PLAIN WORDS**:

By what means can a class object be deep-copied, so that it is totally isolated from its original. Using `copy.deepcopy()` delivers

```
A: 0185; B: 0185;
```

so that is not the solution.

Comment: The way you've defined `x`, it's a _class attribute_, meaning it is inherently shared among all instances of the class.  There's no way for `A.x` and `B.x` to have separate values.  It sounds like you want an _instance attribute_ instead.

Comment: What is your use-case for copying a class?

Comment: @JohnGordon: No, I do not want an instance attribute. I would like to have another class object ```B``` which is just like ```A``` but which I can modify indepently.

Comment: @KlausD. I want to write a function that produces classes. But the class which I clone is defined outside the function, so I cannot rely on instances of locally generated class objects.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer that doesn't make much sense to me. You could write a `clone_class` function rather straight-forwardly, however, I highly suspect this is the X-Y problme

Comment: so, `def clone_class(cls): return type(cls)(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))` would work. But again, I am highly suspicious that your code really needs this. Almost certainly, there is a better way to achieve whatever it is you want to achieve. Essentially, class objects are supposed to be singletons, and like other singletons, `copy.deepcopy(some_singleton) is some_singleton`, so, e.g. `some_singleton = None` or `some_singleton = True`

Comment: Writing a function is not a use-case.

Comment: I agree with @KlausD. you haven't actually described your use-case. You've simply described what you imagine is a solution to your actual problem, but what that problem is isn't clear to me. And now that I think about it, it should probably be `deepcopy(cls.__dict__)` instead of `dict(cls.__dict__)`, but again, this all doesn't really make sense

Comment: Guys, I asked a very clear question for which I would like to get some ideas. Judging if this makes sense or not does not really help.

Comment: Sorry, but these are totally valid comments. In any case, I already gave you an implementation

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Make your implementation an answer and that is absolutely great. If I wanted a precise solution for a specific use case, I would have asked that, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class A:
    x = 123
    def __init__(self):
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        print("original function", self.x)

def g(self):
    print("replacement function", self.x)

B = deepcopy(A)
B.x = 456
B.f = g

a = A()
b = B()
```

This example prints:

```
replacement function 456
replacement function 456
```

Apparently, both `A` as well as `B` share the same values for their attributes `x` and `f`. Therefore, as you have already noted, `copy.deepcopy` doesn't work to "copy" a class object. It seems that Python class objects are singletons, because `A is deepcopy(A)` is `True`.

So, alternatively, you could just use inheritance instead of copying:

```py
class A:
    x = 123
    def __init__(self):
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        print("original function", self.x)

def g(self):
    print("replacement function", self.x)

class B(A):
    pass
B.x = 456
B.f = g

a = A()
b = B()
```

Which prints:

```
original function 123
replacement function 456
```

Like this, we are able to change `B.x` and `B.f` without affecting `A.x` and `A.f`.

However, `isinstance(b, A)` will be `True`, which might be undesired. Also, changes to class attributes of `A` will propagate to its child `B`. Therefore, you just change your original `A` into a dummy `A_`, first, and then derive both `A` and `B` from that:

```py
class A:
    x = 123
    def __init__(self):
        self.f()
    def f(self):
        print("original function", self.x)

def g(self):
    print("replacement function", self.x)

A_ = A
class A(A_):
    pass
class B(A_):
    pass
B.x = 456
B.f = g

a = A()
b = B()
```

Now, `isinstance(b, A)` will be `False` and changes to class attributes of `A` will not propagate to `B`.

Comment: That is the most distinguished answer, I could imagine. Thanks.